# Android Studio, how to disable all those weak warnings in the code?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

Recently I reinstalled Android Studio and now it shows many weak warnings on my Flutter-Dart project, for example for _variable (starting with underscore). I can't find any way to stop AS to show them. And scrollbar is full of lines about those weak warnings.

I went in "Settings - Editor - Inspections" and I disabled *everything*. Well, nothing changed! I succesfully disabled typos in strings but not weak warning.

Where all those weak warning (lowercamelcase identifier, variable starts with underscore, use const, use interpolation to compose strings, etc.) can be handled in Android Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your `analysis_options.yaml` file in the root of your project and set `prefer_const_constructors : false` under the linter->rules sections